# How to mock in JEST document html elements like webview or iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to write some unit tests with Jest for a React component that renders an `<webview>`.
Electron's webview tag is based on Chromium's webview which is some sort of an iframe.

Everytime I run my tests I get into an error when the code riches an event listener method. Here is my code bellow:

```
const TestComponent = (source, iframeError) => {
  const webviewTag = document.querySelector('webview');
  webviewTag.addEventListener('plugin-crashed', (name, version) => {
    console.log(`plugin-crashed: ${name}, ${version}`);
  });

  return (
    <div className="content-body">
      {iframeError
      ? <IframeError />
      : <webivew
          id="webview"
          name="webivew"
          src={source}
          autosize
          allowpopups
          {...optionalAttributes}
          plugins
      />
    }
    </div>
  );
};
```

My test error is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`.

```
  it('should render without crashing', () => {
    shallow(
      <TestComponent iframeError={false} />
    );
  });
```

How do I mock such kind of behaviors in jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one posted an answer, I will do so. Cause I found a way to do it.
So it's possible in `jest` to mock on the `global` object like so:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
  global.document = {
    querySelector: function querySelector() {
      return webviewTag = {
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Let me know if you may see some improvements or other ways to deal with it. Thanks